# Merging two tables

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have two tables with the following descriptions:

```
record(record_id,min_index,max_index)

points(point_id,point_name,val1,val2,rank), point_id being on auto-increment
```

The `min_index`,`max_index` from **record** table points to the point_ids in the point table.
 i.e. for a particular record, the respective points are >=min_index and <=max_index.

I need to merge these two tables such that, the final table resembles something like this

```
points(point_id,record_id,point_name,val1,val2,rank)
```

I know this is against the normalisation criteria, but this seems to work very well with the problem i have. I'm not sure on how to go about merging these two tables.

Comment: can you post some sample data from each table and the expected results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) the tables using MySQL's [`BETWEEN ... AND ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator to specify your join criterion:

```
SELECT points.point_id,
       record.record_id,
       points.point_name,
       points.val1,
       points.val2,
       points.rank
FROM   points JOIN record ON
         points.point_id BETWEEN record.min_index AND record.max_index
```

Comment: Thanks. This certainly helped. I tried the same but without a join and was not exactly happy with the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.point_id,
   b.record_id,
   a.point_name,
   a.val1,
   a.val2,
   a.rank
from points a , record b
where ((point_id>=min_index)and (point_id<=max_index))
```

Comment: I tried this, but without a join, the end results were not matching up to the original values. So yes we just missed out on the join.